# How to get base image in upsells in Magento

Tags: magento

I would like to show the base image in upsells, not the thumbnail or the small image but the image.

I have tried below code in upsell.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_link, 'image')->resize(118,82) ?>
```

But it doesn't work.

Any ideas ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your product collection doesn't have all the attributes for each products, but it has a subset of them, which doesn't include the 'image' attribute.

The quick and dirty way to solve this would be:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId); 
echo '<img src=' . $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image')->resize(118, 82) . ' width=\'118\' height=\'82\'/>';
```

However, the best practise would to find out where is the collection of upsells being loaded and add the image attribute to the collection with `addAttributeToSelect('image')`, so that when you iterate over the collection you don't need to load the product to get that attribute value.

You probably would need to override & extend `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Upsell::_prepareData` (assuming you are using this block), and then, before the collection is loaded, add the following line:

```
 $this->_itemCollection->addAttributeToSelect('image');
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: it will returning placeholder image path, not working.

Comment: Have you loaded the product with `$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_link->getId());`? If the product has an image set, and you've loaded it as showed, it should work.

Comment: Already collection loaded for upsell then why it required reload by load function ? explain please. it is possible without above code ?

Comment: Edited answer with explanation